# Percentage of column total using case when clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using below code to get my result

```
select productId, Year(dateOrdered) Year
  ,isnull(count(case when month(dateOrdered) = 1 then productId end), 0) Jan
  ,isnull(count(case when month(dateOrdered) = 2 then productId end), 0) Feb 
  ,isnull(count(case when month(dateOrdered) = 3 then productId end), 0) Mar
  ,isnull(count(case when month(dateOrdered) = 4 then productId end), 0) Apr
  ,isnull(count(case when month(dateOrdered) = 5 then productId end), 0) May
  ,isnull(count(case when month(dateOrdered) = 6 then productId end), 0) Jun
  ,isnull(count(case when month(dateOrdered) = 7 then productId end), 0) Jul
  ,isnull(count(case when month(dateOrdered) = 8 then productId end), 0) Aug
  ,isnull(count(case when month(dateOrdered) = 9 then productId end), 0) Sep
  ,isnull(count(case when month(dateOrdered) = 10 then productId end), 0) Oct
  ,isnull(count(case when month(dateOrdered) = 11 then productId end), 0) Nov
  ,isnull(count(case when month(dateOrdered) = 12 then productId end), 0) Dec
from Table1
group by productId, Year(dateOrdered)
order by Year(dateOrdered), count(productId) desc;
```

I am getting the count but I want to display values in months columns as percentage of month column total in that particular year.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

```
select productId, 
       Year(dateOrdered) Year,
       sum(case when month(dateOrdered) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / count(*) as Jan,
       sum(case when month(dateOrdered) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / count(*) as Feb,
       ...
from Table1
group by productId, Year(dateOrdered)
order by Year(dateOrdered), count(productId) desc;
```

Comment: getting syntax error for the close bracket after `sum(month(dateOrdered) = 1)`

Comment: The syntax is correct. Did you miss something copying it?

Comment: I am doing it in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio so that might be causing some difference in syntax. For example `select * from Table limit 10` gives syntax error in SSMS but not in SQuirrel while `select top 10 * from Table` works in SSMS!

Comment: @AbhishekV: You tagged your question as MySQL and not SQL-Server. I corrected that and also adjusted my answer.

Comment: I apologize for missing the tag sql-server. This is working but I am getting percentage of row total not the column total.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. It would be best to edit your question and add example data and expected output.